# Rails3 has_many :through and foreign_key not work in set :class_name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**Hi, all**

**I need find friends activities:**

```
SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` 
INNER JOIN `friendships` 
ON `activities`.user_id = `friendships`.friend_id 
WHERE ((`friendships`.user_id = 1))
```

**My add this code to User Model:**

```
has_many :friends_activities, 
         :class_name => 'Activity', 
         :through => :friendships, 
         :foreign_key => :user_id, 
         :source => :friend
```

**But Rails return is:**

```
SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` 
INNER JOIN `friendships` 
ON `activities`.id = `friendships`.friend_id 
WHERE ((`friendships`.user_id = 1))
```

**I need :**

```
`activities`.user_id = `friendships`.friend_id
```

**But Now:**

```
`activities`.id = `friendships`.friend_id
```

**PS: My Tables:**

```
create_table "activities", :force => true do |t|
     t.integer  "user_id"
     t.integer  "target_id"
     t.string   "target_type"
     t.string   "verb"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "friendships", :force => true do |t|
     t.integer  "user_id",    :null => false
     t.integer  "friend_id",  :null => false
     t.string   "state"
     t.datetime "created_at"
     t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Comment: what version of Rails3 is this a RC or a beta release

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can use the additional options on the has_many :through. According [to the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> Specifies an association through which to perform the query. This can
>   be any other type of association, including other :through
>   associations. **Options for :class_name, :primary_key and :foreign_key
>   are ignored**, as the association uses the source reflection.

[emphasis mine]

Answer (score 0):

Your last resort might be:

```
has_many :friends_activities, 
         :class_name => 'Activity', 
         :finder_sql => Proc.new {
            %Q{
               SELECT `activities`.* FROM `activities` 
               INNER JOIN `friendships` 
               ON `activities`.user_id = `friendships`.friend_id 
               WHERE ((`friendships`.user_id = #{id}))

              }
          }
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to achieve this, but in the meantime this should do the work.